# What is the cofinality of $\omega+1$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

so $\omega+1=\{\{0,1,2,...\},\{\omega\}\}$, it seems to be the case that $cf(\omega+1)=1$, since $1=|\{\omega\}|$ is the least cardinality of cofinal subsets of $\omega+1$, but $1$ is also the cofinality of the ordinal $2$, which is much less than $\omega+1$. How can I overcome this contradiction?

Comment: Rather than $\{\{0,1,2,...\},\{\omega\}\}$, you mean the union of this set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no contradiction; cofinality is not a strictly increasing function. Indeed, the cofinality of every non-zero successor ordinal (i.e., ordinals $\alpha$ such that $\alpha = \beta + 1$ for another ordinal $\beta$) is $1$.

One way to think about cofinality of an ordinal $\alpha$ is that it measures how long a sequence needs to be in order to "reach" $\alpha$, not how big $\alpha$ is.

Comment: But then $cf(\omega)=\omega$, and $\omega$ is less than $\omega+1$ and has a bigger cofinality?

Comment: Yes. In fact, $cf(\omega) > cf(\aleph_{\aleph_\omega} + 1)$, or indeed any other suitably monstrously huge successor ordinal.

Comment: @SidCaroline Why would you expect $cf(\alpha)$ to be strictly increasing?

Comment: I guess my intuition was wrong. I thought that a bigger ordinal must have a bigger cardinality, so it must have a bigger cofinality.

Comment: @Sid: The cofinality of $\omega_1+\omega$ is still countable.

Comment: Duncan, *"every non-zero successor ordinal"*, since when is zero a successor ordinal? :D

Comment: SidCaroline Note that that isn't true even for limit ordinals. $cf(\aleph_0) < cf(\aleph_1) < ...$, but $cf(\aleph_\omega) = \omega$.

@AsafKaragila Since the first set theory textbook I used included them ;).