# What does $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$ stand for?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

My guess is that it's the cardinality of $\omega_{\omega_{\omega}}$. Since $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of $\omega$ and $\omega$ is a limit cardinal, so it must be that $\aleph_0=\omega$. (Is this true in general?) Then I can just substitute the subscript $\aleph_0$ with $\omega$, and I do the same thing again. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you meant to write $\omega$ is a limit ordinal. Are you working in a context in which the cardinals are not represented as ordinals? Please be more specific about your problem with the notation.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715321/if-the-infinite-cardinals-aleph-null-aleph-two-etc-continue-indefinitely-is/

Answer (score 5):

Without any further context, the cardinality of $\omega_{\omega_\omega}$ seems to be the most reasonable guess at the meaning, but the notation is not standard. The subscript in $\aleph_{n}$ is supposed to be an *ordinal number*, not a cardinal number, so the standard notation for this would be $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$.

If this interpretation makes sense in context, I would assume it is just a misnaming of $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$, unless you're positively sure the $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$ notation comes from someone who definitely knows what they're talking about.

---

(If you're asking due to the comment on [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407056/what-is-the-cofinality-of-omega1), I'm pretty sure Duncan just meant $\omega_{\omega_\omega}$ -- but not because there's anything special about *that* ordinal; any other large-looking ordinal could have been used to make the point he was making).

Comment: Assuming Wikipedia and AC, [the cardinality of a set X is the least ordinal number α such that there is a bijection between X and α](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition), so one could interpret $\aleph_\alpha$ to be an ordinal.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Yes, but in this particular case there's the extra wrinkle that there are two different notations $\omega_\alpha$ and $\aleph_\alpha$ for _the same set_, with the strong convention that you write $\omega_\alpha$ whenever you're thinking of it as an ordinal, and (usually) write $\aleph_\alpha$ when you're thinking of it as a cardinal number. The existence of that convention is what makes me declare this particular case to be likely to be a typo.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: The issue here is context. The successor cardinal of $\aleph_\alpha$ is $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$, but $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$, because the $\aleph$ notation implies cardinal arithmetic. Therefore, the successor of $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ should not be denoted by $\aleph_{\aleph_0+1}$. So if the successor of $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ is $\aleph_{\omega_\omega+1}$, might as well call the bastard by its name and use $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$ from the get go.

Comment: (Oops, I had too many $\omega$'s in the subscript of my previous comment. $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ corresponds, of course, to $\aleph_\omega$ and not $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$...)

Answer (score 4):

It would be more appropriate to write this as "$\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$" - the index of an expression is supposed to be an ordinal, not a cardinal. And this is indeed the cardinality of the ordinal $\omega_{\omega_\omega}$.

However, [cardinals are usually defined *as* initial ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment), so e.g. $\aleph_0=\omega$; it's just that we often use two different names for these entities, to distinguish between their roles in a mathematical argument. So technically the expression is fine as written, if a bit odd.